# Firebase Mobile number Authentication issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Error :

> testing.html:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: sendOTP is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (testing.html:20:51)
> onclick   @   testing.html:20

I am trying to build a test Mobile number and OTP ver. website using firebase. I am getting this error in console when i am inserting the mobile number and clicking Send OTP button.

My HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Firebase OTP Verification</title>
    <!-- Add Firebase SDK -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth-recaptcha-compat.js"></script>

    <!-- Include your separate script -->
    <script src="firebase-script.js" type="module"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>OTP Verification</h1>
    <form id="otpForm">
        <label for="phoneNumber">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" required>
        <button type="button" onclick="sendOTP()">Send OTP</button>

        <label for="otp">Enter OTP:</label>
        <input type="text" id="otp" required>
        <button type="button" onclick="verifyOTP()">Verify OTP</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript code:-

```js
// firebase-script.js
import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-app.js';
import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber, RecaptchaVerifier } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.10/firebase-auth.js';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC01PgXhZ9-9BP01GTWJSs473fmGz5n7Kk",
    authDomain: "otp-verification-27a65.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "otp-verification-27a65",
    storageBucket: "otp-verification-27a65.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "25699686034",
    appId: "1:25699686034:web:b56ff82c6a8685d57cf84b",
    measurementId: "G-P0YV1RSGXT"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

function sendOTP() {
    const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phoneNumber').value;
    const appVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('otpForm');

    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, `+${phoneNumber}`, appVerifier)
        .then((confirmationResult) => {
            window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
            console.log("OTP Sent!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error sending OTP: ", error.message);
        });
}

function verifyOTP() {
    const otp = document.getElementById('otp').value;
    window.confirmationResult.confirm(otp)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("OTP Verified!");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error verifying OTP: ", error.message);
        });
}
```

I want that the OTP gets verified and the page is redirected to another webpage.

Comment: You're not exporting `sendOTP` from the module, and also not importing it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69888029/how-to-call-a-function-declared-in-a-javascript-module-type-module-from-an-htm and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630310/use-functions-defined-in-es6-module-directly-in-html