Why is my pageLoad function suddenly undefined when I convert my javascript file to a module?
I've been developing a javascript application the old fashion way. That is, by referencing scripts one after the other in the html page header:
    <head>
        ...
        <script src="./helpers.js"></script>
        <script src="./pwvlogic.js"></script>
    </head>

But I would like to treat helpers.js as a module and import it into pwvlogic.js, and then remove the reference to it from the html page.
Here's what helpers.js looked like before the change:
function createLineDiv(line) {
    ...
}

function fillActionButtonsContainer(actionButtonsContainer, line) {
    ...
}
  
function highlightSearchString(content) {
   ...
}

And here's what it looks like after the change:
export function createLineDiv(line) {
    ...
}

export function fillActionButtonsContainer(actionButtonsContainer, line) {
    ...
}
  
export function highlightSearchString(content) {
   ...
}

export default {
   createLineDiv,
   fillActionButtonsContainer,
   highlightSearchString
}

And in pwvlogic.js, I add an import statement at the top:
import { createLineDiv, fillActionButtonsContainer, highlightSearchString } from './helpers.js';

Then in the html file, I remove the reference to helpers.js and add type="module" to the pwvlogic.js reference:
<script src="./pwvlogic.js" type="module"></script>

Now there is an issue with loading the pageLoad() function. In my html, I have this:
<body onload="pageLoad()">

And in pwvlogic.js, I have the pageLoad function:
function pageLoad() {
   ...
}

In the browser, I get the error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: pageLoad is not defined

Why is pageLoad suddenly undefined? Can I not reference it in a javascript module the same way I can a regular javascript file? How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Have you searched here on stackoverflow for this problem? There are existing answers, for examle https://stackoverflow.com/a/53630402/20901722  and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888825/20901722

Ah, yes, these articles concur with La Ngoc. Thanks Ray!

pageLoad() is scoped to its module, it's not a property of global object. You might need to make it a property of window if you want to use it in regular js


<body onload="hello()">
  <script type="module">
    function hello() { 
      console.log("hello") 
    } 
    window.hello = hello
  </script>
</body>




Thanks La Ngoc! Adding the functions to window works!
